# How can i do app that bring toast on time that was set by user before?

Tags: android

I want to make an app which will bring toast(no matter where is the user) on time that was set by user before.So,can i do this app in one class? 1) If yes,then must I extend that class by Activity? 2) If no,then can i use the class which extends by Service for the alarm manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should you `BroadcastReceiver`  for your case, setup an alarm that starts the `BroadcastReceiver` and within the `BroadcastReceiver` call

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("myData") != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("myData"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain why should i use BroadcastReceiver and  not a Service

Comment: simply because you said you only wanna show toast message, services are meant for jobs that needed to be done for example long jobs.

Comment: and what if i want to check is current app running in the moment,what should i use?Thanks for help:)